# php file_get_contents for post and consuming REST

Tags: php, web-services, rest

On a sample code I provided for a recent interview, I used file_get_contents for consuming their web service(nothing special sending some custom headers for a POST request). I find other methods like curl unnecessarily complex and verbose and use file_get_contents for most of the "client" stuff I do with PHP.

One interviewer argued that, file_get_contents is not recommended for anything but get requests. I did not object on the spot but went back and googled a little bit. Can't find any reliable answers on his assertion of this "commonly known fact"

Can anyone point at some disadvantages for using file_get_contents in this context? Also can anyone point me to a resource where they eliminate file_get_contents as a good practise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From a security perspective, using `file_get_contents()` is generally not a good idea.

#### allow_url_fopen

For `file_get_contents()` to be able to use remote sources, the setting `allow_url_fopen` must be enabled. But when enabling this setting, all other stream related functions in PHP (like `include` and `require`) are also allowed to use remote sources. This could allow attacks like [Remote File Execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability).

When using another tool, like cURL, you can disable `allow_url_fopen` (it's enabled by default).

#### SSL/TLS

PHP streams are insecure over SSL/TLS by default. Luckily this can be corrected, but it does need attention before you can securely use HTTPS/FTPS sources.

A remaining issue is that PHP is unable to match Subject Alternative Names in certificates (which many certificates use). This means that (when configured securely) PHP can reject a valid certificate. In order to circumvent this, you'll need to disable CN matching, which opens you up to [Man In The Middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

cURL on the other hand is fully secure by default, and does support SAN matching.

#### Survive The Deep End: PHP Security

Pádraic Brady is writing a book on PHP Security, which has [this chapter](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Transport-Layer-Security-%28HTTPS-SSL-and-TLS%29.html#ssl-tls-from-php-server-to-server) that you might want to read.

#### Guzzle

You might want to have a look at [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client that makes it easy to work with HTTP/1.1 and takes the pain out of consuming web services. It uses cURL by default.

Comment: Hi Jasper, solid point on SSL/TLS I did not know this. But correct me if I am wrong allow_url_fopen is only a security threat if your codebase is vulnerable for injections. If you are the owner of a box to provide shared hosting, by all means disable allow_url_fopen.

Comment: Indeed, `allow_url_fopen` doesn't form a risk when you filter user-input correctly. But filtering user-input is hard, or rather it's easy to forget a case because you simple didn't think of that possibility. So my motto is: if you don't need it, disable it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents()` for more than simple GET requests, by passing a [stream_context](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-create.php). But then it will soon get as complex as with cURL or others, while being (IMHO) less intuitive.

It is true, as pointed out by Jasper, that `file_get_contents()` requires `allow_url_fopen=1`, which again may be a security threat. However, allow_url_fopen is active on most hosts anyway, and personally I think there are worse security pitfalls in PHP.

My conclusion would be: If you build an application only for yourself, use `file_get_contents()` or cURL. If you need portability, use one of the libraries that implement HTTP clients on raw sockets, such as Snoopy.

Comment: Monte Ohrt's "[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/files/latest/download)". Wow - it's still around and maintained. +1 for that. It uses `stream_socket_client()` or `fsockopen()` and `stream_context_create()`. And is quite lightweight compared to class monsters like Guzzle etc. Ok, no PSR coding style.. but hey, it works!

Comment: Yeah, I had to check if it's still maintained before recommending it here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Best for this use Curl. The fact that Curl has many settings:

- The ability to specify a timeout request
- The ability to choose GET or POST
- The ability to pass cookies
- The ability to use the BASIC AUTH
- etc

for all of these and other such things is difficult to use file_get_contents. To use the curl was not so difficult i recommend write a wrapper class.

Comment: everything you mentioned is possible and easier -if not same- with file_get_contents

Comment: @kali I cannot imagine how to configure all these options for file_get_contents. The PHP manual seems mute on this. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: which one do you need Lorenz? I can write a quick sample